# How can I get all the objects associated through the intermediate table by ServiceStack.OrmLite?

Tags: ormlite-servicestack

I'm a beginner who has just started using ServiceStack.OrmLite. I have a question.  How can I get all the objects associated through the intermediate table?

details as following:

```cs
Public class book
{
    Public int id { get; set; }
    Public string name { get; set; }
    [Reference]
    Public List<bookusers> bookusers { get; set; }
}

Public class bookusers
{
    Public int id { get; set; }
    Public int bookid { get; set; }
    Public int userid { get; set; }
    [Reference]
    Public book book { get; set; }
    [Reference]
    Public user userObject { get; set; }
}

Public class user
{
    Public int id { get; set; }
    Public int age { get; set; }
    [Reference]
    Public List<bookusers> userbooks { get; set; }
}
```

---

```cs
var model = db.LoadSingleById<book>(id);
db.LoadReferences(model);
// model.bookusers[0].userObject is null
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't directly retrieve second level references as [stated in documentation](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite#querying-pocos-with-references).

> Loads related data only 1-reference-level deep

A quick and dirt working method could be the next

```
var model = db.LoadSingleById<book>(id);
if (model.bookusers != null && model.bookusers.Any())
{
    foreach (var bookUser in model.bookusers)
    {
        db.LoadReferences(bookUser);
    }
}
```

Then you should have your `userObject` property populated.